# C++11: What prevents stores from lifting past the start of a lock's critical section?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, language-lawyer, memory-model

My understanding is that a spinlock can be implemented using C++11 atomics with
an acquire-CAS on lock and a release-store on unlock, something like this:

```
class SpinLock {
 public:
  void Lock() {
    while (l_.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire));
  }

  void Unlock() {
    l_.clear(std::memory_order_release);
  }

 private:
  std::atomic_flag l_ = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
};
```

Consider its use in a function that acquires a lock and then does a blind write
to some shared location:

```
int g_some_int_;

void BlindWrite(int val) {
  static SpinLock lock_;

  lock_.Lock();
  g_some_int_ = val;
  lock_.Unlock();
}
```

I'm interested in how the compiler is restricted in translating this to
generated assembly code.

I understand why the write to `g_some_int_` can't migrate past the end of the
critical section in the compiler's output -- that would mean that the write
isn't guaranteed to be seen by the next thread that acquires the lock, which is
guaranteed by the release/acquire ordering.

But what prevents the compiler from moving it to before the acquire-CAS of the
lock flag? I thought that compilers were allowed to re-order writes to different
memory locations when generating assembly code. Is there some special rule that
prevents a write from being re-ordered to before an atomic store that precedes
it in program order?

I'm looking for a language lawyer answer here, preferably covering `std::atomic`
as well as `std::atomic_flag`.

**Edit** to include something from the comments which maybe asks the question
more clearly. The heart of the question is: which part of the standard says that
the abstract machine must observe `l_` being `false` before it writes to
`g_some_int_`?

I suspect the answer is either "writes can't be lifted above potentially
infinite loops" or "writes can't be lifted above atomic writes". Perhaps it's
even "you're wrong that writes can ever be re-ordered at all". But I'm looking
for a specific reference in the standard.

Comment: The `memory_order_acquire` on the lock and `memory_order_release` on the unlock accomplish this. See `memory_order`.

Comment: I don't see why the compiler wouldn't be allowed to move the assignment after `Unlock`, either. In your example, there's no way for a valid, race-free program to ever observe the value of `g_some_int_` anyway, unless there's some additional, external synchronization.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Please read my question again, grepping for "which is guaranteed by the release/acquire ordering". I can see why what you say is true for one reordering, but not for the other.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: You're right at the C++ level, but I'm asking about the location of the store in the generated assembly code. There's not the same notion of races there, and re-ordering in that way would cause incorrect behavior according to the release/acquire ordering model. I just don't see where the memory model guarantees the same thing for the `Lock` call.

Comment: The memory model is a C++-level notion. It doesn't say anything about "generated assembly code", only about observable behavior of a program. The compiler is free to generate any assembly that leads to the observable behavior of the resulting program matching one of the possible executions of the abstract machine specified by the standard. For example, a compiler capable of whole program optimization could notice that you never ever read `g_some_init_`, and optimize away the whole `BlindWrite` function to a no-op.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I completely agree; that is the background for my question. The question itself is: which part of the standard says that the abstract machine must observe `l_` being unset before it writes `g_some_int_`? I suspect the answer is either "writes can't be lifted above potentially infinite loops" or "writes can't be lifted above atomic writes". But I'm looking for a specific reference in the standard.

Comment: [intro.multithread.10] shows that the release in `Unlock` is dependency-ordered before the acquire in `Lock`. [intro.execution.14] shows that the `Lock` is sequenced before the load of `g_some_int_`, and that the the store to `g_some_int_` is sequenced before the `Unlock`. [atomics.order.2] shows that the release in `Unlock` is synchronized with the acquire in `Lock`. Therefore [intro.multithread.11] the write to `g_some_int_` inter-thread-happens before the read of `g_some_int_`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks, but there was no read of `g_some_int_` in my question. :-) I was only asking about hoisting writes. The answer from Anthony covers what I was looking for.

Comment: `which part of the standard says that the abstract machine must observe l_ being unset before it writes g_some_int_?` **1.9/14** Every value computation and side effect associated with a full-expression is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with the next full-expression to be evaluated. **6/1** Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence.

Comment: If there are no reads from `g_some_int_`, then the reordering is not observable, so the issue is moot. The compiler could optimize out the `g_some_int_` variable entirely. I'm assuming that somewhere else in the code there is a protected read of `g_some_int_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have two functions that use your spinlock:

```
SpinLock sl;
int global_int=0;

int read(){
    sl.Lock();
    int res=global_int;
    sl.Unlock();
    return res;
}

void write(int val){
    sl.Lock();
    global_int=val;
    sl.Unlock();
}
```

If two calls to `BlindWrite` happen concurrently on separate threads, then one (call it A) will acquire the lock; the other (B) will spin in the loop in `Lock`.

A then writes to `g_some_int`, and calls `Unlock`, which contains a call to `clear` which is a *store-release*. The write is *sequenced-before* the call to `clear` since it is in the same thread.

B then wakes in `Lock`, and this time the `test_and_set` call returns `false`. This is a *load-acquire* that read the value stored by the call to `clear`, so the call to `clear` *synchronizes-with* this call to `test_and_set`.

The `test_and_set` call in `Lock` is a load-acquire, and is *sequenced-before* the write to `g_some_int` in `BlindWrite`, since it is in the same thread.

Since the first write in thread A is *sequenced-before* the call to `clear`, which *synchronizes-with* the call to `test_and_set` in thread B, which is in turn *sequenced-before* the write in thread B, the write in thread A *happens-before* the write in thread B.

If the compiler hoisted the write to `g_some_int` above the call to `Lock`, then it would be possible for the write from thread B to occur before the write in thread A. This would violate the *happens-before* ordering, so is not permitted.

In general, this means that the compiler cannot hoist **anything** above a *load-acquire*, since it may violate the *happens-before* ordering.

Comment: This is how I understood it, correct me if I'm wrong: _Sequenced-before_ basically applies to all operations executing on the same thread. The reason the compiler is allowed to reorder those instructions in the first place is that he can violate _sequenced-before_ ordering as long as he's obeying the _as-if rule_. In a single-threaded context that simply means not reordering a read before a write to the same data. In a multithreaded context, it also means taking into account _synchronizes-with_ constraints from atomics and locks.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was looking for. I can't find a sentence in the standard that specifically says the abstract machine has to obey the happens before relationship in its side effects, but it seems pretty natural to assume that is implied. Thank you!

Comment: **1.9/13** Given any two evaluations `A` and `B`, if `A` is sequenced before `B`, then the execution of `A` shall precede the execution of `B`.

Comment: The *happens-before* ordering is covered in 1.9 and 1.10, and how it relates to atomics is in 29.3. It is quite hard to follow, but it is all there. The *abstract machine* has to follow the requirements, because the requirements for the abstract machine are what the standard specifies!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Thanks, that plus the quote you gave in the other comment thread ("Except as indicated, statements are executed in sequence") is exactly what I was looking for. Anthony, I agree it's natural that it obeys happens-before. :-) I was just wondering if it was stated explicitly somewhere.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams: I've asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45475241/1505451) if you're interested in having a look...

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams What are the elementary operations of the evaluation of a program where the abstract machine requirements have to be followed?

Comment: @curiousguy Abstract machine operations are I/O, and access to `volatile` objects: https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.abstract#6

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams I don't understand how that "abstract machine" is supposed to do computations.

Comment: @curiousguy by magic, or any other mechanism that produces the correct sequence of I/O and `volatile` accesses.

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams OK but that doesn't say what the "correct" sequence is! "_The abstract machine has to follow the requirements_" It isn't clear what is required for an MT program (unlike non threaded)

Comment: There isn't a single correct sequence, except in very special cases. A possible correct sequence is anything that doesn't violate the constraints in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec